# Are Azure App Service and Notification Hub shareable with 2 or more android apps?

Tags: android, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-notificationhub

Azure newly introduced App Service and Notification hub with C# back end shareable with 2 or more android Apps?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes - the backend and client are independent.  You just need to ensure the right URLs and secrets are used throughout.  The server offers services - the client consumes (potentially a subset of) those services.